# How to check when docker daemon was restarted on widows?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-daemon

I am running Docker Daemon on a windows server and I have several containers running on it.
In the last 2 days, the server was not restarted but the containers suddenly stopped running. When I open docker dashboard the containers show as they are restarting.

What could be the reason of the containers suddenly stopping? My suspicion is that the daemon is stopping for some reason, but I don't know how to check when it was actually stopped/started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the docker daemon logs on windows in 2 locations:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Docker
```

and

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Romaing\Docker\log\vm
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, logs will be saved here in Windows:

C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Docker

Format is log.X.txt, numbered sequentially.  The logs will show much more information than the dashboard - you can search by "Error" or "Warning" which are elevated events, as opposed to typical "Info" log entries.

To find a single daemon start (or stop), look for an event like this:

[GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Starting C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe -addr unix:\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer -native-api

[GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Started